RecursionError when importing libraries in Jupyter Notebook
I installed Jupyter Notebook on my new computer. When I am trying to import python libraries, some raise no errors, and others (known libraries that I have worked with before) raise a recursion error with the following message:
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 3
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import ruptures

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruptures/__init__.py:4
      1 """Offline change point detection for Python."""
      3 from .datasets import pw_constant, pw_linear, pw_normal, pw_wavy
----> 4 from .detection import Binseg, BottomUp, Dynp, KernelCPD, Pelt, Window
      5 from .exceptions import NotEnoughPoints
      6 from .show import display

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruptures/detection/__init__.py:3
      1 r"""Search methods."""
----> 3 from .binseg import Binseg
      4 from .bottomup import BottomUp
      5 from .dynp import Dynp

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruptures/detection/binseg.py:6
      4 import numpy as np
      5 from ruptures.base import BaseCost, BaseEstimator
----> 6 from ruptures.costs import cost_factory
      7 from ruptures.exceptions import BadSegmentationParameters
      8 from ruptures.utils import pairwise, sanity_check

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruptures/costs/__init__.py:11
      9 from .costautoregressive import CostAR
     10 from .costml import CostMl
---> 11 from .costrank import CostRank
     12 from .costcosine import CostCosine

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruptures/costs/costrank.py:4
      2 import numpy as np
      3 from numpy.linalg import pinv, LinAlgError
----> 4 from scipy.stats.mstats import rankdata
      6 from ruptures.base import BaseCost
      7 from ruptures.costs import NotEnoughPoints

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py:610
      1 """
      2 .. _statsrefmanual:
      3 
   (...)
    605 
    606 """  # noqa: E501
    608 from ._warnings_errors import (ConstantInputWarning, NearConstantInputWarning,
    609                                DegenerateDataWarning, FitError)
--> 610 from ._stats_py import *
    611 from ._variation import variation
    612 from .distributions import *

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py:49
     46 # Import unused here but needs to stay until end of deprecation periode
     47 # See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/15765#issuecomment-1875564522
     48 from scipy import linalg  # noqa: F401
---> 49 from . import distributions
     50 from . import _mstats_basic as mstats_basic
     52 from ._stats_mstats_common import _find_repeats, theilslopes, siegelslopes

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py:10
      1 #
      2 # Author:  Travis Oliphant  2002-2011 with contributions from
      3 #          SciPy Developers 2004-2011
   (...)
      6 #       instead of `git blame -Lxxx,+x`.
      7 #
      8 from ._distn_infrastructure import (rv_discrete, rv_continuous, rv_frozen)  # noqa: F401
---> 10 from . import _continuous_distns
     11 from . import _discrete_distns
     13 from ._continuous_distns import *  # noqa: F403

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:12
     10 import numpy as np
     11 from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
---> 12 from scipy.interpolate import BSpline
     13 from scipy._lib.doccer import (extend_notes_in_docstring,
     14                                replace_notes_in_docstring,
     15                                inherit_docstring_from)
     16 from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/__init__.py:167
      1 """
      2 ========================================
      3 Interpolation (:mod:`scipy.interpolate`)
   (...)
    165 (should not be used in new code).
    166 """
--> 167 from ._interpolate import *
    168 from ._fitpack_py import *
    170 # New interface to fitpack library:

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_interpolate.py:12
      9 from scipy._lib._util import copy_if_needed
     10 from scipy.special import comb
---> 12 from . import _fitpack_py
     13 from ._polyint import _Interpolator1D
     14 from . import _ppoly

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_py.py:8
      5 import numpy as np
      7 # These are in the API for fitpack even if not used in fitpack.py itself.
----> 8 from ._fitpack_impl import bisplrep, bisplev, dblint  # noqa: F401
      9 from . import _fitpack_impl as _impl
     10 from ._bsplines import BSpline

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py:103
     52 _iermess = {
     53     0: ["The spline has a residual sum of squares fp such that "
     54         "abs(fp-s)/s<=0.001", None],
   (...)
     68     'unknown': ["An error occurred", TypeError]
     69 }
     71 _iermess2 = {
     72     0: ["The spline has a residual sum of squares fp such that "
     73         "abs(fp-s)/s<=0.001", None],
   (...)
     99     'unknown': ["An error occurred", TypeError]
    100 }
    102 _parcur_cache = {'t': array([], float), 'wrk': array([], float),
--> 103                  'iwrk': array([], dfitpack_int), 'u': array([], float),
    104                  'ub': 0, 'ue': 1}
    107 def splprep(x, w=None, u=None, ub=None, ue=None, k=3, task=0, s=None, t=None,
    108             full_output=0, nest=None, per=0, quiet=1):
    109     # see the docstring of `_fitpack_py/splprep`
    110     if task <= 0:

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_dtype.py:46, in __repr__(dtype)
     45 def __repr__(dtype):
---> 46     arg_str = _construction_repr(dtype, include_align=False)
     47     if dtype.isalignedstruct:
     48         arg_str = arg_str + ", align=True"

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_dtype.py:100, in _construction_repr(dtype, include_align, short)
     98     return _subarray_str(dtype)
     99 else:
--> 100     return _scalar_str(dtype, short=short)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_dtype.py:143, in _scalar_str(dtype, short)
    140 elif dtype.type == np.timedelta64:
    141     return "'%sm8%s'" % (byteorder, _datetime_metadata_str(dtype))
--> 143 elif np.issubdtype(dtype, np.number):
    144     # Short repr with endianness, like '<f8'
    145     if short or dtype.byteorder not in ('=', '|'):
    146         return "'%s%c%d'" % (byteorder, dtype.kind, dtype.itemsize)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py:417, in issubdtype(arg1, arg2)
    359 r"""
    360 Returns True if first argument is a typecode lower/equal in type hierarchy.
    361 
   (...)
    414 
    415 """
    416 if not issubclass_(arg1, generic):
--> 417     arg1 = dtype(arg1).type
    418 if not issubclass_(arg2, generic):
    419     arg2 = dtype(arg2).type

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_dtype.py:46, in __repr__(dtype)
     45 def __repr__(dtype):
---> 46     arg_str = _construction_repr(dtype, include_align=False)
     47     if dtype.isalignedstruct:
     48         arg_str = arg_str + ", align=True"

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_dtype.py:100, in _construction_repr(dtype, include_align, short)
     98     return _subarray_str(dtype)
     99 else:
--> 100     return _scalar_str(dtype, short=short)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_dtype.py:143, in _scalar_str(dtype, short)
    140 elif dtype.type == np.timedelta64:
    141     return "'%sm8%s'" % (byteorder, _datetime_metadata_str(dtype))
--> 143 elif np.issubdtype(dtype, np.number):
    144     # Short repr with endianness, like '<f8'
    145     if short or dtype.byteorder not in ('=', '|'):
    146         return "'%s%c%d'" % (byteorder, dtype.kind, dtype.itemsize)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py:417, in issubdtype(arg1, arg2)
    359 r"""
    360 Returns True if first argument is a typecode lower/equal in type hierarchy.
    361 
   (...)
    414 
    415 """
    416 if not issubclass_(arg1, generic):
--> 417     arg1 = dtype(arg1).type
    418 if not issubclass_(arg2, generic):
    419     arg2 = dtype(arg2).type

    [... skipping similar frames: __repr__ at line 46 (475 times), _construction_repr at line 100 (475 times), _scalar_str at line 143 (475 times), issubdtype at line 417 (475 times)]

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_dtype.py:46, in __repr__(dtype)
     45 def __repr__(dtype):
---> 46     arg_str = _construction_repr(dtype, include_align=False)
     47     if dtype.isalignedstruct:
     48         arg_str = arg_str + ", align=True"

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_dtype.py:100, in _construction_repr(dtype, include_align, short)
     98     return _subarray_str(dtype)
     99 else:
--> 100     return _scalar_str(dtype, short=short)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_dtype.py:143, in _scalar_str(dtype, short)
    140 elif dtype.type == np.timedelta64:
    141     return "'%sm8%s'" % (byteorder, _datetime_metadata_str(dtype))
--> 143 elif np.issubdtype(dtype, np.number):
    144     # Short repr with endianness, like '<f8'
    145     if short or dtype.byteorder not in ('=', '|'):
    146         return "'%s%c%d'" % (byteorder, dtype.kind, dtype.itemsize)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/reg_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py:417, in issubdtype(arg1, arg2)
    359 r"""
    360 Returns True if first argument is a typecode lower/equal in type hierarchy.
    361 
   (...)
    414 
    415 """
    416 if not issubclass_(arg1, generic):
--> 417     arg1 = dtype(arg1).type
    418 if not issubclass_(arg2, generic):
    419     arg2 = dtype(arg2).type

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the repr of an object

This happens with other libraries as well.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!
Iv'e tried the solution of:
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(3000)

but it did not help.
